# Adding filter entries to the git config file

Tags: git

If I run:

```
git config foo.bar hello
```

It adds the following to my repo's local .git\config file:

```
[foo]
    bar = hello
```

But now suppose that I want to add the following to that same config (which is what's used by [lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/), but that's beyond the point):

```
[filter "lfs"]
  clean = git-lfs clean %f
  smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
  required = true
```

**Question: Is there a git command that will add this?**

I have not been able to make `git config` work here, because the key would need to be something like `filter "lfs".clean` which it doesn't view as a valid key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command would be:

```
$ git config filter.lfs.clean 'git-lfs clean %f'
$ git config filter.lfs.smudge 'git-lfs smudge %f'
$ git config filter.lfs.required true
```

The part in quotes just becomes the second level of the config key.

Comment: On Windows, I had to use double quotes instead of single quotes. E.g.: `git config filter.lfs.clean "git-lfs clean %f"`.

Comment: On Windows, if you call this from a CMD batch file, you have to escape the `%f` as `%%f` like e.g.: `git config filter.lfs.clean "git-lfs clean %%f"`.